# How can I enter my passphrase only once in Git CMD?

Tags: git, command-prompt, ssh-agent, git-for-windows

After installing Git for Windows, I am using Git CMD (not Git Bash). I have a passphrase-protected private key stored at `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/id_rsa`

I am running a script that performs Git actions on multiple repos. Every time it interacts with a new repo I have to enter my passphrase again.

Is there any way I can enter my passphrase only once (kind of like Pageant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. After you launch Git CMD run

```
start-ssh-agent
```

You will be prompted for your passphrase, and the ssh-agent will store your private key for future use (you can find the `ssh-agent.exe` process in your Task Manager).

Any Git commands that are used after that will access your private key via ssh-agent, until the end of your desktop session.